# Xelatex issue when using Xelatex template

Tags: xetex, templates

I'm experiencing a problem when using a cover letter template I downloaded from http://www.latextemplates.com/cat/cover-letters.

Here's my preamble:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{fontspec} % Allows font customization
\usepackage{marvosym} % Allows the use of symbols
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage[danish, english]{polyglossia}


\setlength\parindent{0pt} % Removes all indentation from paragraphs

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont {Adobe Garamond Pro} % Main document font
\setsansfont{Gill Sans MT}
%\setsansfont {Gill Sans} % Used in the from address line above the to address

\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{12.5}{17}\selectfont} % Sets the font size and leading

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% ÊPERSONAL INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\setkomavar{fromname}{Joakim Blach Andersen} % Your name
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Sankt Peders Stræde 14\\City\\Country} % Your address
\setkomavar{fromphone}{(000) 111-1111} % Your phone number
\setkomavar{fromemail}{john@smith.com} % Your email address
\setkomavar{place}{} % City written before the date, put your city here if you want this
\setkomavar{signature}{John Smith} % Your name as you want it to appear in the signature

% These are not used in this document, uncomment if you would like to use them and refer to them as \usekomavar{name}
%\setkomavar{fromfax}{+1 (1)23 456789} % Your fax number
%\setkomavar{fromurl}{http://www.johnsmith.com} % Your personal website
%\setkomavar{frombank}{Postbank 9307157}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% ÊHEADER SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\firsthead{
\centering
{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=20.0}\fontsize{36}{36}\selectfont\scshape \usekomavar{fromname}}\\[5mm]
\fontsize{21}{21}\selectfont\scshape Programmer at Initech } % Your current job title

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% ÊFOOTER SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\firstfoot{
\centering
\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=20.0}\scshape
{
\renewcommand{\\}{\ {\large\textperiodcentered}\ }
\usekomavar{fromaddress}
}\\
{\Large\Letter} \usekomavar{fromemail} \ {\Large\Telefon} \usekomavar{fromphone} % If you want your fax number or website URL showing, add it here; you may need to play around with spacing
}"


And here's me messages:

"\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{fontspec} % Allows font customization
\usepackage{marvosym} % Allows the use of symbols
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage[danish, english]{polyglossia}


\setlength\parindent{0pt} % Removes all indentation from paragraphs

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont {Adobe Garamond Pro} % Main document font
\setsansfont{Gill Sans MT}
%\setsansfont {Gill Sans} % Used in the from address line above the to address

\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{12.5}{17}\selectfont} % Sets the font size and leading

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% ÊPERSONAL INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\setkomavar{fromname}{Joakim Blach Andersen} % Your name
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Sankt Peders Stræde 14\\City\\Country} % Your address
\setkomavar{fromphone}{(000) 111-1111} % Your phone number
\setkomavar{fromemail}{john@smith.com} % Your email address
\setkomavar{place}{} % City written before the date, put your city here if you want this
\setkomavar{signature}{John Smith} % Your name as you want it to appear in the signature

% These are not used in this document, uncomment if you would like to use them and refer to them as \usekomavar{name}
%\setkomavar{fromfax}{+1 (1)23 456789} % Your fax number
%\setkomavar{fromurl}{http://www.johnsmith.com} % Your personal website
%\setkomavar{frombank}{Postbank 9307157}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% ÊHEADER SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\firsthead{
\centering
{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=20.0}\fontsize{36}{36}\selectfont\scshape \usekomavar{fromname}}\\[5mm]
\fontsize{21}{21}\selectfont\scshape Programmer at Initech } % Your current job title

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% ÊFOOTER SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\firstfoot{
\centering
\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=20.0}\scshape
{
\renewcommand{\\}{\ {\large\textperiodcentered}\ }
\usekomavar{fromaddress}
}\\
{\Large\Letter} \usekomavar{fromemail} \ {\Large\Telefon} \usekomavar{fromphone} % If you want your fax number or website URL showing, add it here; you may need to play around with spacing
}"
```

I'm fairly new in Latex and Xelatex, so I really hope you guys can point out the issue here. I tried deleting the package "danish" but then it is the same issue with "english". As I understood "polyglossia" is used in stead of "babel" so that's what I did.

Hope you guys can figure it out.

---

Here's what I have now.

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{fontspec} % Allows font customization
\usepackage{marvosym} % Allows the use of symbols
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{danish}

\setlength\parindent{0pt} % Removes all indentation from paragraphs

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
%\setmainfont {Adobe Garamond Pro} % Main document font
\setmainfont {times} % Main document font

%\setsansfont{Gill Sans MT}
\setsansfont{times}

%\setsansfont {Gill Sans} % Used in the from address line above the to address

\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{12.5}{17}\selectfont} % Sets the font size and leading

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% ÊPERSONAL INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\setkomavar{fromname}{Joakim Blach Andersen} % Your name
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Sankt Peders Stræde 14\\City\\Country} % Your address
\setkomavar{fromphone}{(000) 111-1111} % Your phone number
\setkomavar{fromemail}{john@smith.com} % Your email address
\setkomavar{place}{} % City written before the date, put your city here if you want this
\setkomavar{signature}{John Smith} % Your name as you want it to appear in the signature

% These are not used in this document, uncomment if you would like to use them and refer to them as \usekomavar{name}
%\setkomavar{fromfax}{+1 (1)23 456789} % Your fax number
%\setkomavar{fromurl}{http://www.johnsmith.com} % Your personal website
%\setkomavar{frombank}{Postbank 9307157}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% ÊHEADER SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\firsthead{
\centering
{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=20.0}\fontsize{36}{36}\selectfont\scshape \usekomavar{fromname}}\\[5mm]
\fontsize{21}{21}\selectfont\scshape Programmer at Initech } % Your current job title

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% ÊFOOTER SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\firstfoot{
\centering
\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=20.0}\scshape
{
\renewcommand{\\}{\ {\large\textperiodcentered}\ }
\usekomavar{fromaddress}
}\\
{\Large\Letter} \usekomavar{fromemail} \ {\Large\Telefon} \usekomavar{fromphone} % If you want your fax number or website URL showing, add it here; you may need to play around with spacing
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% COVER LETTER CONTENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{letter}{ % Address of the company you are applying to
HR Dept. --- Corporation\\
123 Pleasant Lane\\
12345 City, State
}

\setkomavar{subject}{Cover Letter} % This is the bold text saying 'Cover Letter', remove it if you don't like it

\opening{Dear Recruiter,}

PARAGRAPH ONE: State the reason for the letter, name the position or type of work you are applying for and identify the source from which you learned of the opening.\\

PARAGRAPH TWO: Indicate why you are interested in the position, the company, its products, services - above all, stress what you can do for the employer. If you are a recent graduate, explain how your academic background makes you a qualified candidate for the position. If you have practical work experience, point out specific achievements or unique qualifications. Try not to repeat the same information the reader will find in the resume. The purpose of this section is to strengthen your resume by providing details which bring your experiences to life.\\

PARAGRAPH THREE: Request a personal interview and indicate your flexibility as to the time and place. Repeat your phone number in the letter. End the letter by thanking the employer for taking the time to consider your credentials.\\

Sincerely yours, \\ \\ \\
\usekomavar{signature}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

And my error:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{fontspec} % Allows font customization
\usepackage{marvosym} % Allows the use of symbols
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{danish}

\setlength\parindent{0pt} % Removes all indentation from paragraphs

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
%\setmainfont {Adobe Garamond Pro} % Main document font
\setmainfont {times} % Main document font

%\setsansfont{Gill Sans MT}
\setsansfont{times}

%\setsansfont {Gill Sans} % Used in the from address line above the to address

\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{12.5}{17}\selectfont} % Sets the font size and leading

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% ÊPERSONAL INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\setkomavar{fromname}{Joakim Blach Andersen} % Your name
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Sankt Peders Stræde 14\\City\\Country} % Your address
\setkomavar{fromphone}{(000) 111-1111} % Your phone number
\setkomavar{fromemail}{john@smith.com} % Your email address
\setkomavar{place}{} % City written before the date, put your city here if you want this
\setkomavar{signature}{John Smith} % Your name as you want it to appear in the signature

% These are not used in this document, uncomment if you would like to use them and refer to them as \usekomavar{name}
%\setkomavar{fromfax}{+1 (1)23 456789} % Your fax number
%\setkomavar{fromurl}{http://www.johnsmith.com} % Your personal website
%\setkomavar{frombank}{Postbank 9307157}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% ÊHEADER SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\firsthead{
\centering
{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=20.0}\fontsize{36}{36}\selectfont\scshape \usekomavar{fromname}}\\[5mm]
\fontsize{21}{21}\selectfont\scshape Programmer at Initech } % Your current job title

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% ÊFOOTER SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\firstfoot{
\centering
\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=20.0}\scshape
{
\renewcommand{\\}{\ {\large\textperiodcentered}\ }
\usekomavar{fromaddress}
}\\
{\Large\Letter} \usekomavar{fromemail} \ {\Large\Telefon} \usekomavar{fromphone} % If you want your fax number or website URL showing, add it here; you may need to play around with spacing
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% COVER LETTER CONTENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{letter}{ % Address of the company you are applying to
HR Dept. --- Corporation\\
123 Pleasant Lane\\
12345 City, State
}

\setkomavar{subject}{Cover Letter} % This is the bold text saying 'Cover Letter', remove it if you don't like it

\opening{Dear Recruiter,}

PARAGRAPH ONE: State the reason for the letter, name the position or type of work you are applying for and identify the source from which you learned of the opening.\\

PARAGRAPH TWO: Indicate why you are interested in the position, the company, its products, services - above all, stress what you can do for the employer. If you are a recent graduate, explain how your academic background makes you a qualified candidate for the position. If you have practical work experience, point out specific achievements or unique qualifications. Try not to repeat the same information the reader will find in the resume. The purpose of this section is to strengthen your resume by providing details which bring your experiences to life.\\

PARAGRAPH THREE: Request a personal interview and indicate your flexibility as to the time and place. Repeat your phone number in the letter. End the letter by thanking the employer for taking the time to consider your credentials.\\

Sincerely yours, \\ \\ \\
\usekomavar{signature}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: According to page 3 of the [polyglossia package documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/polyglossia), selecting the language using a package option is no longer supported. You need to use `\setmainlanguage{danish}`. If that doesn't solve your problem, please edit your question to include a short, complete example (i.e. everything from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`).

Comment: Okay I used "\setmainlanguage" and it seemed to solve a part of the problem. Now I have a new problem it seems. It does say "process exited normally" in the end, but in my pdf document all the danish letters are replaced by different looking squares. 

Any ideas?

Thanks again.

Comment: I tried substituting the fonts with "times" or "arial" but then I just get a fontspec error.

Answer (score 3):

`polyglossia` uses a different way to declare languages:

```
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{danish}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping out. Indeed that solved something, since I don't get that error anymore. Now it does say "Process exited normally", though when I open my pdf file, all the danish letters such as "æ" and "ø" are replaced with a square or something??

Comment: @JoakimBlachAndersen Did you try with other fonts?

Comment: Yes I tried with several fonts now. "times" was the first I tried. As soon as I change the fonts I get the error:

"! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "verdana" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>."

Comment: It's really odd..